# How do I assign read-only access to a user role in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, roles

I need a user role, who is able to see a full woocommerce order, but can't edit, delete or process the order. Is this possible? If so, how would you go about it?

Comment: may be this plugin can help you. https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: Members is another widely used plugin for setting user permissions: https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/